# react-native-iap and revenueCat difference

Tags: ios, react-native, revenuecat, react-native-iap

So I've integrated `react-native-iap` in my app for subscription feature, but I 've read some of the docs online which suggests to use `RevenueCat` library, I've tested in sandbox & storekit and working fine for now but one of the doc says it works fine in sandbox but won't work in live so cna anyone suggests me the better way please...?